# Where does windows commandline ftp download to?

Tags: command-line, ftp, windows-7-x64

I am running ftp in windows command line and the operating system in windows 7.

Where do files get downloaded to locally when i do a get operation?

Comment: Any reason why this is getting downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line ftp client uses the current working directory (which can be changed with the `lcd` command)